# How to test App on a real iphone using Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, testing

As **Xcode 6** is quite new, and the layout is a bit different from Xcode 5. I have no idea how to test my App on a real iphone using Xcode 6. I want to **test my App on my iPhone 5s**. I have joined the developer programme. Are there any step by step tutorials? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to attach your device with machine and select it from Xcode?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-test-your-app-on-an-ios-device--mobile-13861 check it.

Answer (score 3):

After xCode5 this process is more easier. Plug your device, run you project with the device selected

[image]

xcode will automatically created a provision profile for you.

You **need first** to associate your apple account with xcode

**xCode->Preferences->Accounts**

Answer (score 3):

If the above description doesn't work,

1. Just start XCode 6
2. Connect your iPhone 5S
3. Select "Devices" in the Window menu
4. Select your iPhone 5S on the left side under "Devices"
5. Press on "Use Device for development"

From this point on, you should be able to select your iPhone 5 as destination for the build.

XCode 6 has the Organizer split into "Organizer" and "Devices" so maybe you are just missing the "Devices" screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just connect your phone to your mac with the USB cable, and then select your device like this:

[image: Preview]